# Pyinstaller Error - "setuptools distribution was not found"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build an executable binary for my Python project using PyInstaller.

**Environment Details:**

Python - 2.7.6, pip - 6.1.1, setuptools - 21.2.1

I can build the project successfully:

```
pyinstaller heatstackapp.py
......
......
83093 INFO: checking COLLECT
83093 INFO: Building COLLECT because out00-COLLECT.toc is non existent
83094 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
jayaprakash@cloudenablers:/opt/core/heatstack/heatstack$
```

but when I execute the binary, it throws the following error message:

```
jayaprakash@cloudenablers:/opt/core/heatstack/heatstack$     ./dist/heatstackapp/heatstackapp 
......
......
      File "pbr/packaging.py", line 31, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
        exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
      File "setuptools/command/develop.py", line 11, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
        exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
      File "setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 53, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
        exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
      File "setuptools/package_index.py", line 206, in <module>
      File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
      File "pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'setuptools' distribution was not found and is required by the application
    Failed to execute script heatstackapp
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a package or set of files that are not being included in the final `.exe` file by PyInstaller. This happens when PyInstaller cannot automatically detect the modules needed, or extra data files that are not scripts (and therefore not a part of your chain of imports and dependencies).

I cannot tell more from the information provided, but can give some general steps to take.

---

#### Update the `.spec` file and run PyInstaller on it, rather than your `.py` file.

When you run PyInstaller on your `.py` file, a `.spec` file will first be created, then PyInstaller will generate the `.exe` from the `.spec` file.

After running PyInstaller once, you can edit the `.spec` file manually to include additional "hidden" imports and direct resource/data files (like images, metadata files, etc.) that PyInstaller can't find on it's own.

After manually updating the `.spec` file, don't run PyInstaller on the `.py` file anymore. Instead, run it directly on the `.spec` file, and it will build the `.exe` with the extra resources that you manually specified.

See also [this answer on a utility bundled with PyInstaller that can make a `.spec` file for different cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48912788/6501141).

#### Add data files to the `.spec` file

In the spec file, there is a `datas =` line that can be updated in a very specific format to include individual files or entire folders with their content.

- See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile) for more information.
- See the [PyInstaller Docs on Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)

#### Hidden Imports

If PyInstaller is missing some needed imports (usually because a particular package is using some implicit, non-standard method of managing one or more of its dependencies), you can tell PyInstaller in the `.spec` file to include it anyway.

See [PyInstaller Docs on Hidden Imports](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports).