# Using --onefile with a .spec in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm "compiling" a program using PyInstaller using a .spec file. I'm using the .spec file because I need to include an extra file in the program. When I try to do `PyInstaller --onefile Prog.spec`, it still makes a folder in `dist` with all the files separate instead of making a single file as I'd expect. If I do `PyInstaller --onefile Prog.py` then it does make a single .exe file in `dist`, which is what I want. Is there something special I need to do when using a .spec file?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `pyi-makespec --onefile yourprogram.py` to generate a sample spec file for onefile mode.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyi-makespec.html

---

There is no COLLECT call, and the EXE call is different. Example:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add the extra file on the command line instead of editing the spec file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST> yourfile.py
```

Otherwise, make sure in the spec file there is no collect step:

"In one-file mode, there is no call to COLLECT, and the EXE instance receives all of the scripts, modules and binaries."

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html for more info on command line flags.

This also may offer some insight if problems persist: [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)