# Building one file eel python aplication with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel

After building distributable binary with PyInstaller

```
python.exe -m eel --onefile  c:\Users\Darek\PycharmProjects\eelTest\web\  c:\Users\Darek\PycharmProjects\eelTest\eelTest.py
```

When I try run app I got this error

```
Failed to extract C:\Users\Darek\PycharmProjects\eelTest\web\main.html: failed to open target file!
fopen: Invalid argument
```

[image: eel test]

How to fix it?

Comment: You can check this link [using --onefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143315/using-onefile-with-a-spec-in-pyinstaller)

Comment: I'm using --onefile (-F)

Comment: please create a [mre]